# Question Regarding Solving for Theta within a Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry, theta-functions

I am currently puzzled over how to deal with the following exercise:

$$2\cos(\theta)-1=0$$

Here is the work I have done so far concerning the listed equation:

$$2\cos(\theta)-1=0 \\2\cos(\theta)=1 \\\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2} \\\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n \text{ or } \theta=\frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi n$$

You would think that this is the solution however the obstacle which has stopped me in my tracks is the $k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Let me explain. For each of the two solutions which I found, I have added $2\pi n$ since if $2\pi$ is added no matter how many times the point will land on the same place on the unit circle for any value. I think that perhaps the $k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ is an expression used in mathematics which acts much like a synonym to the $2 \pi n$ which I have added to each solution. I ask of you to inform me more of $k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and its use within the listed problem. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: So your problem is that it''s $2\pi n$ instead of $k\pi$? You can relabel $2n=k.$

Comment: To rephrase my inquiry, could k(pi) with kez be substituted for 2(pi)n? If so, just to be clear, theta= (pi)/3+2k(pi) with kez is the answer to the question, correct?

Comment: No. Not every integer multiple of $\pi$ will give correct solutions.

Comment: Could the same not apply to n? As in, when the variable n is used, it does not necessarily imply that only whole numbers are to be substituted for n?

Comment: You haven’t said anywhere what set of values $n$ can have.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the problem is, as you said, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n \text{ or } \theta=\frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (you can add or subtract $2\pi$ and the cosine doesn't change).

But the solution isn't $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi k \text{ or } \theta=\frac{5\pi}{3}+\pi k$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$! For example, you can check what happens with $k=1$: if you add (or subtract) $\pi$ then the angle is actually different and the cosine might change. Long story short: the coefficient before the "$k\pi$" is important and you have to write it.

Another example: $\cos \alpha = 0$, then $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$. Here it appears the "$k\pi$", and not the "$2k\pi$". This happens because the solutions are "actually" $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \text{ or } \alpha=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$, and the other notation (in this case) is equivalent.

Comment: To fix the issue which you have noted, would it be acceptable to add 2(pi)k with kez so as all possible addition to both (pi)/3 and (5(pi))/3 would be multiples of 2, making the solutions correct?

Comment: @James3423 you can write $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi k \text{ or } \theta=\frac{5\pi}{3}+\pi k$ with $k\in 2\mathbb{Z} = \{0, \pm 2, \pm 4, \ldots\}$ but the best thing is to be clear

Comment: Is it also possible to write 2(pi)k with kez without specifying kez? By the way, if you have time to, please inform me of the meaning of (pi)k with kez.

Comment: @James3423 it depends: if it appears for the first time in a text, then the best is to write it and then (maybe) you can omit it if it is clear from the context. What do you mean with " the meaning of $k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$"? Also: you can find a tutorial of mathjax latex here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: By meaning, I mean to say use. For example, the sigma notation is used to express the addition of variables from one number up to another for a given equation.

Comment: the meaning of "$2k\pi$" and "$k\pi$" with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the same: it means that the set of the solutions is formed by a "base" solution and all the others are the base one plus a specific angle. For example $\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi$ means $\{\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3} + 1\cdot \pi,\frac{\pi}{3} - 1\cdot \pi, \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\cdot \pi,\ldots\}$, while $\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$ means $\{\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\cdot 1\cdot \pi,\frac{\pi}{3} - 2\cdot 1\cdot \pi, \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\cdot2\cdot \pi,\ldots\}$. It is like the $\pm$ when you write the solutions of the second degree equations.

Comment: To conclude this discussion, if required to put the answer of the exercise in such a way that included k(pi) with kez, the following would be correct:

Comment: theta=(pi)/3 + 2k(pi), kez

Comment: or theta= (5(pi))/3 +2k(pi), kez

Comment: @James3423 yes, it is correct (as I wrote in my answer!): writing $2n\pi$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ or $2k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ is the same

Comment: Quick question, is it implied when using either k or n in this case that the variables can only be whole numbers? If not, wouldn't that make the above solutions invalid?

Comment: @James3423 $n,k$ in some contexts are integers, in other contexts are whatever you can imagine: this is why it is important to write $k\in\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots\}$! If $k$ is not an integer, then $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$ is not a solution: try with $k=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you for your overflowing help! I have gained a concrete understanding of this concept due to your assistance.